# Best way to find nested property by name in object

Tags: javascript, loops, object, key-value

I have an object (dataLayer), which can increase and decrease in length, depending on how many pages you've visited.

I want to:

- Loop through the objective and look for the property name "ecommerce".
- I specifically want to find the value of "brandcode".
- Must be in the same object group as "pagetitle: `Login Page"

Obviously, I can do `dataLayer['4'].ecommerce.information. product`.  However, the problem I have this that this key/value position could be at any number.  EG dataLayer[0],[1],[2],[12] etc

What is the best way to loop through this object and look for this key/value pair, regardless of it's index in the object?

```js
const dataLayer = 
  { 0: { a: 123, event: 'pageload', productId: 1 } 
  , 1: { b: 456, event: 'pageload', productId: 3 } 
  , 2: {         event: 'gtm.load', productId: 3 } 
  , 3: {         event: 'gtm.load', productId: 4 } 
  , 4: 
    { pagetitle: 'Login Page'
    , ecommerce: 
      { information: 
        { product: 
          [ { brandCode: 'car', productColor: 'red' } 
          , { brandCode: 'car', productColor: 'green' } 
          , { brandCode: 'car', productColor: 'yello' } 
          ]   
  } } } };
```

Thanks,

Comment: `1: ab {a: {…}}` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It was just an example, you can ignore (I've updated it with another example).

Comment: After you parse the data, what is the expected output? An array?

Comment: Probably all the best practices to iterate objects are collected into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/1169519

Comment: PS, your `product {[{ brandCode: "car", productColor: "red" }];}` is an invalid Object - it has no *key* - Please do your best to post a valid entry data and explain the expected output

Comment: `Object.keys()` will give you an array of object's keys. You can iterate over the keys and look for a key named `ecommerce` in the corresponding value of each key in the array.

Comment: `{[{ brandCode: "car", productColor: "red" }];}` is still invalid after your second edit

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - it's a nested object.

Comment: @ReenaVerma Nope, it's a syntax error, the array in the object must have a key.

Comment: `{key: value}` is correct. But you have: `{value}`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I get that, this is just an example. I'm trying to get the theory right.  Any ideas, would be helpful

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I've taken this from a real working example.  It's a nested object, products is an array, which contains 3 other data entries.

Comment: @mister jojo please refrain from modifying invalid data posted by OP. And use the default formatter. Thank you.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan and wher are the coma ? your dataLayer is not a valid js object

Comment: @MisterJojo sorry it was a wrong [Revision Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65289663/revisions)

Comment: @ReenaVerma thank you for specifying that `products` is an Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to strip out ES6, as the tool I'm using only allows ES5. But with this solution, I can take the last entry/update of `ecommerce.information` to the dataLayer, by adding it into a new array and then slicing the last entry.

```
var productArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dataLayer.length; i++) {
    if (dataLayer[i].ecommerce) {
        for (var line in dataLayer[i].ecommerce.information) {
            var itemProducts = dataLayer[i].ecommerce.information;
            productArray.push(itemProducts);
        };
    };
};

var lastItem = productArray.slice(-1);

if (lastItem[0].product[0].brandCode === "car") {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Roko C. Buljan's solution is also helpful, as this is isolated to the pagetitle, which I will also playaround with as well.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

this way  with for( **of** ) and for( **in** )

```js
const dataLayer = 
  { 0: { a: 123, event: 'pageload', productId: 1 } 
  , 1: { b: 456, event: 'pageload', productId: 3 } 
  , 2: {         event: 'gtm.load', productId: 3 } 
  , 3: {         event: 'gtm.load', productId: 4 } 
  , 4: 
    { pagetitle: 'Login Page' , fx:false, trduc: { madchin: 'bidule'}
    , ecommerce: 
      { information: 
        { product: 
          [ { brandCode: 'car', productColor: 'red'   } 
          , { brandCode: 'car', productColor: 'green' } 
          , { brandCode: 'car', productColor: 'yello' } 
          ]   
  } } } }
  ;
for (let key in dataLayer) // key value are '0','1',...,'4'
  {
  if ( 'ecommerce' in dataLayer[key]
    && dataLayer[key]?.pagetitle==='Login Page'
    ) {
    for (let prod of dataLayer[key].ecommerce.information.product)
      {
      console.log( prod.brandCode, prod.productColor )
  } } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

[edit]

I have added a verification on  `pagetitle==='Login Page'` see [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
and corrected the test on the existence of the `ecommerce` property
see [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Comment: Thank you so much @Mister Jojo!!  This is really helpful!!!

Comment: @ReenaVerma I have added a verification on  `pagetitle==='Login Page'`  ;) (ES10 JS code)

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve an array of brandcodes from specifically `"Login Page"`

```js
const dataLayer = {
  0: {event: 'pageload', productId: 1, a: 123},
  1: {event: 'pageload', productId: 3, b: 456},
  2: {event: 'gtm.load', productId: 3},
  3: {event: 'gtm.load', productId: 4},
  4: {
    pagetitle: 'Login Page',
    ecommerce: {
      information: {
        product: [
          {brandCode: 'car', productColor: 'red'},
          {brandCode: 'truck', productColor: 'green'},
          {brandCode: 'bike', productColor: 'yello'},
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  17: {
    pagetitle: 'Login Page',
    ecommerce: {
      information: {
        product: [
          {brandCode: 'cow', productColor: 'lila'},
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};


function getEcommerceBrandCodes(pagetitle, data) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((a, [k, ob]) => {
    const isPagetitle = ob.hasOwnProperty("pagetitle") && ob.pagetitle === pagetitle;
    const isEcommerce = ob.hasOwnProperty("ecommerce");
    if (isPagetitle && isEcommerce) {
      a.push(ob.ecommerce.information?.product?.map(item => item.brandCode));
    }
    return a;
  }, []).flat();
}

console.log(getEcommerceBrandCodes("Login Page", dataLayer));
```